# Alternative of AbpSession.Use() in abp framework (abp.io)

Tags: abp

In asp.net boilerplate, we can use `IAbpSession.Use(userId, tenantId)` to override current session.

When I upgraded to abp framework (abp.io), I don't know how to migrate it.

I found only `CurrentTenant.Change(tenantId)` to override current tenant, but I can't find any way to change current user.

Answer (score 1):

I found that
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/CurrentUser#changing-the-current-principle

It seems that, the `CurrentUser` in abp framework works with principal instead of UserId only.

> If you don't make sense about pricipal, please reference Claims-based authentication, the principal is an identity that contains several claims.

So if we want impersonating an user, we should replace the whole principal.

There is an open issue about it: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/1082